# pandas python legend not showing all color categories

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a graph using dataframe values, I have three columns in the dataframe, column one is the legend values of the graph, column two is the x axis and column third is the y-axis. When I am plotting the graph it is only showing me one category in the legend not all, its showing me only one color

This is my dataframe

[image]

This is my code

```
ax1 = graphdf.plot(kind='bar', x='Bottles', y='bottle Avg')
figures = graphdf['fig'].tolist()
ax1.legend(labels=figures, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
for p in ax1.patches:
    label1 = "{:.1f}".format(p.get_height())
    ax1.annotate(label1, xy=(p.get_x() * 1.015, p.get_height() * 1.015))
```

but this is only showing 1 categories in the label not all.

This is the output, I want to show all categories in the legend

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In this usage [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) calls [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html) exactly once, creating a single collection of patches with a single label. The [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.legend.html) signature where only the labels are specified simply assigns labels to "*existing plot elements*". Since `plt.bar` creates a single "plot element" only one legend entry is created. You can easily get around this by using the third call signature for `ax.legend`, where **both** the labels and handles are specified, i.e.

```py
ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='Bottles', y='bottle Avg')
ax.legend(labels=df['fig'].tolist(), handles=ax.patches, fancybox=True, shadow=True)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate("{:.1f}".format(p.get_height()), xy=(p.get_x() * 1.015, p.get_height() * 1.015))
```

[image]